# Nginx - rewrite or return for redirection?

Tags: linux, nginx

I've got two options (return and rewrite) for redirection and I'm not sure which is recommended for performance, SEO, etc:

```
## Redirect from non-www to www
server {
        server_name example.com;
        # Option 1
        return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;

        # Option 2
        rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

## Default server config

server {
        ...
        listen      192.168.1.1:80 default_server;
        root        /www;
        server_name www.example.com;
```

Option 2 seems to work with curl but it's not redirecting when called by a browser and the return code is that of a temporary redirect despite the rewrite directive being set to `permanent`:

```
 curl -I example.com
 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
 Server: nginx
 ...
 Location: http://www.example.com/
 ...
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your option 1:

```
return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;
```

Is exactly what you want.

Not sure why the `rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri? permanent;` line would result in a 302 instead of 301. That's the proper syntax to force it to return a 301.

Comment: I had to add "listen" directive to the first server block. It works fine however when I try to access the admin backend (Wordpress - wp-admin) there is some kind of loop and I can't get into the login page. Any ideas?

Comment: That would probably be better dealt with in a separate question. Sounds like both your software (wordpress) and nginx are doing some redirecting, resulting in a loop.

Answer (score 7):

Technically, you can use both options. They can work.

According to the [NGINX documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/), **use `return` if you can**. It is simpler and faster because NGINX stops processing the request (and doesn't have to process a regex). More than that, you can specify a code in the *3xx* series:

```
return (301 | 302 | 303 | 307) url;
```

If you have a scenario where you need to validate the URL with a regex or need to capture elements in the original URL (that are obviously not in a corresponding NGINX variable), then you should use `rewrite`. You must know that `rewrite` returns only code 301 or 302.

```
rewrite regex URL [flag];
```

You can read more about [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) and [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) on the NGINX website.

Comment: rewrite looks pretty nasty and like a horrific code smell to me.